# Better way to store column data config CSV file for later searching and usage

Tags: c#

I have a CSV configuration file for my program that I read in on launch and store into various arrays for later use. It contains two columns (for now) of paired data, like so:

1,10
2,14
3,11
Blue,4-10202
Red,4-10001

In this snippet of the file, the first three lines are only used once and I do the following:

```
int[][] BayPortMap = new int[10][]; 

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   BayPortMap[i] = new int[3];
}

var contents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\CSI\MotorTesterConfig.csv");
contents = contents.Where(x =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Trim(','))).ToArray();
var csv = from line in contents select line.Split(',');
int HeaderRows = 1;
foreach (var row in csv.Skip(HeaderRows))
{
   if (csvindex < 10)
   {
       BayPortMap[csvindex][0] = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
       BayPortMap[csvindex][1] = Convert.ToInt32(row[1]);
       BayPortMap[csvindex][2] = -1;
   }
}
```

Now here's the part I don't like. I do the same for the next two lines but later in the program I need to search for the 2nd column values and when I find a match, I need to act on the 1st column data. So when the user scans a number, i.e. 4-10002, that returns Blue and then act on that.

```
MotorPNArray[index] = new string[2];
MotorPNArray[index][0] = row[0];
MotorPNArray[index][1] = row[1];
```

It will work buts feels clunky. Another program I will write later has many columns of "data" that will need to get used based on a matching PN.

So, should I keep doing it this way or use something else, i.e. List, etc.

Comment: You might consider using a Database.

Comment: Create a class that supports the data you need and serialize it to disk, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656715.aspx for example. Or use a (NoSQL) db like http://www.litedb.org/

Comment: Should I maybe just search the CSV file instead and get the data that way? That's seams not the best either, pulling it into ram in some type that I can work on seems nicer?? I should add, the CSV file needs to be (easily) end user updateable, so no DB.

Comment: Did some more searching, I think what I'm after is a KeyValuePair and for more data columns, a Tuple. Thoughts or examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> MotorPNDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        int csvindex = 0;
        int HeaderRows = 1;
        foreach (var row in csv.Skip(HeaderRows))
        {
           if (csvindex < 10)
           {
              /* Here we get the Bay/Port mapping and store them in ascending order regardless of the CSV order, i.e. bay 1 will always be array position 0*/
              var index = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]) - 1;
              BayPortMap[index][0] = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
              BayPortMap[index][1] = Convert.ToInt32(row[1]);
              BayPortMap[index][2] = -1;
           }
           else
           {
              switch (csvindex)
              {
                 case 10:
                    {
                       TesterNumber = row[1];
                       break;
                    }
                 case 11:
                    {
                       ReportLocation = row[1];
                       break;
                    }
                 case 12:
                    {
                       DBSource = row[1];
                       break;
                    }
                 case 13:
                    {
                       InitialCatalog = row[1];
                       break;
                    }
                 default:
                    {
                       /* add Motor PNs and there corresponding types to a dictionary */
                       MotorPNDict.Add(row[1], row[0]);
                       break;
                    }
              }
           }
           csvindex++;
        }
```